# Saving nested entities in Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am having trouble saving my entities via REST with Spring Data Rest.
As you can see below I have a circular dependency which I try to solve with Jackson. This is a small example explaining the problem.

#### Account

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(property = "id", generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)
public class Account implements Serializable
{
    @Id <...>
    private Long id;

    private String uid;

    @OneToMany <...>
    //@JsonIdentityReference
    private List<AccountIdentifier> identifiers;

    // Getters, Setters ...
}
```

#### AccountIdentifier

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(property = "id", generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)
public class AccountIdentifier implements Serializable
{
    @Id <...>
    private Long id;

    private String value;

    @ManyToOne <...>
    //@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
    private Account account;

    // Getters, Setters ...
}
```

#### AccountRepository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "accounts", path = "accounts")
public interface AccountRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Account, Long>
```

#### AccountIdentifierRepository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "accountidentifiers", path = "accountidentifiers")
public interface AccountRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<AccountIdentifier, Long>
```

With this setup I can perfectly read values stored in my database.

The Problem starts, when I want to save values via `POST` to my `/accounts` endpoint. I want to save the following JSON:

```
 '{"id":null, "uid":"test-uid", "identifiers":[{"id":null,"value":"test-value"}]}'
```

This raises a `JsonMappingException`:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: demo.domains.AccountIdentifier["account"]->demo.domains.Account["identifiers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->demo.domains.AccountIdentifier["account"]-[...]
```

When I annotate both entities with `@JsonIdentityReference` I get `NullPointerExceptions` on the circular reference.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: demo.domains.Account["identifiers"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->demo.domains.AccountIdentifier["account"])
```

Is there any way to store both the Account and the nested AccountIdentifier with `"id":null`?
I want to avoid to do two `POST`s to the different endpoints. Using `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` has other unwanted drawbacks.

It works perfectly when I use the entity objects in Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have no choice and must do various POST. I've struggled a lot with that, playing with bi- and uni-directional associations, to arrive at this conclusion.

The easiest you can do is to `POST` on `/account` with an empty `identifiers`, then on `/accountidentifiers` with an `account` field equals to the `location` field inside the answer to your first `POST`, and you won't need to `PATCH` again your account entity to update the relationship.

Comment: Thanks for your insights. It will work that way. I ended up deleting the identifier repository and using the identifiers via the account repository. It's a bigger overhead, but I can avoid a second `POST`.